# Memory is building up after matric inversion in Armadillo (C++)

Tags: c++, memory-management, out-of-memory, armadillo, rcpparmadillo

I am working with Armadillo and there seems to be some weird memory management in my program.
I need to solve a matrix system recursively, and for this I call the following function in a for-loop :

```
void get_T(arma::cx_vec &T, arma::mat M0, arma::vec Q, int dim, int nmem){

    int n;
    n = pow(2 * dim, nmem);

    arma::cx_mat M(n, n);
    arma::cx_mat P(n, n);
    arma::cx_mat InvP(n, n);
    arma::vec U(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        U(i) = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            M(i, j) = std::complex<double>(0, 0);
            P(i, j) = std::complex<double>(0, 0);
            InvP(i, j) = std::complex<double>(0, 0);
        }
    }

    get_M(M, M0, Q, dim, nmem);
    P = arma::eye(n, n) - M;
    InvP = P.i();
    T = InvP * U;
}
```

I checked the overall RSS memory taken by the entire program, and it seems that the step involving P.i() increases the amount of memory used (which makes sense), but it does not free it when the program exits the get_T function. So the overall memory keeps increasing as the for-loop continues, which in the end leads to a huge amount of memory required. How can I fix this ? I read that Armadillo cleans up memory every time it exits a function, but it does not seem to do it here.

Thanks for helping !

Comment: "_... does not free it when the program exits the get_T function_" - It probably does, but it's not seen on the OS side. Freeing memory doesn't automatically make it available for other processes. It's usually kept available to the process that allocated it in the first place in case it needs to allocate it again.

Comment: Ok I see, thanks. Any chance I can force it in some way ?

Comment: You're welcome. No, not that I know of. Perhaps there's something you could do by patching the kernel - but why? See  [Force memory release to the OS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32683736/7582247). The [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32683737/7582247) may be something for you if you _really_ want it.

Comment: I need to run this code on a computing cluster and it gets killed as soon as the memory usage exceeds the one that was allocated for the job. So in this case I need to ask for a large amount of memory in order to launch it, which is very unpractical...

Comment: If the memory usage increases far beyond what you expect (and have requested from the cluster), you probably have a leak somewhere. Have you executed your application locally compiled with `-fsanitize=address` etc? `valgrind` may also be an option to try to find leaks.

Comment: Generally there is no need to take the inverse if you only need to solve a system. Use the [solve()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#solve) function instead of inv(). Try this: `T = arma::solve( (arma::eye(n, n) - M), U );`.  There are other problem in your code. To reduce memory usage, pass matrices by reference wherever possible instead of copying. In the function declaration, use `const arma::mat& M0` instead of `arma::mat M0`. To clear matrices, using [.zeros()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#zeros_member) is more efficient than manually setting each element to zero.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.
I have tried with the solve command but I get the following error when compiling :

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘solve(arma::enable_if2<true, const arma::mtGlue<std::complex<double>, arma::Gen<arma::Mat<double>, arma::gen_ones_diag>, arma::Mat<std::complex<double> >, arma::glue_mixed_minus> >::result, arma::vec&)’
     T = arma::solve( (arma::eye(n, n) - M), U );
```

Comment: Looks like arma::solve is not working for complex matrices.

Comment: arma::solve() works for complex matrices, but my example was wrong. The solve() function requires the input matrices and vectors to have the same element type (`std::complex<double>` in this case). Try this instead: `T = arma::solve( P, arma::conv_to<arma::cx_vec>::from(U) );`  The [conv_to](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#conv_to) function converts between matrix/vector types.

Comment: That works indeed thanks, but that does not solve the memory issue.
But it looks like this is really an OS problem. I have written a very simple code in which basically only arma::solve is called, and run valgrind with this code.
There is no problem at all when I run it on my laptop, but it returns a large amount of errors when I run it on the computing cluster I am working with. Don't know what to do now..

Comment: You can use [.reset()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#reset) to force the release the memory. Maybe that would help?  Another option is to ensure the latest version of Armadillo is installed on the cluster.  [Reporting](http://arma.sourceforge.net/faq.html) the problem to the Armadillo developers may also help (showing the output of valgrind could be useful).