# memory leak of virtual memory

Tags: c++, linux, memory-management, memory-leaks

I run tensorflow on linux (ubuntu20). TF executes my c++ functions for graph compilation/destruction.

The consumption of the process virtual memory grows until out-of-memory (>40GB) and the process is killed.

I track `malloc`/`free` and `mmap`/`munmap` with `LD_PRELOAD` hook and compare with the process virtual memory consumption from /proc/self/status (VmSize).
Each graph compilation increases both malloc-allocated and the process virtual memory by almost the same size.

Graph destruction decreases malloc-allocated size but not the process virtual memory.

So in spite of malloc-allocated memory staying overall stable, the process virtual memory grows fast.

e.g.:

```
before compile: 41MB[mmap]/3320MB[malloc]/12428MB[process]
after  compile: 46MB[mmap]/7434MB[malloc]/16529MB[process]
before destroy: 46MB[mmap]/7436MB[malloc]/16593MB[process]
after  destroy: 46MB[mmap]/3250MB[malloc]/16593MB[process]
```

`graphDestroy` does not destroy everything by design so a small leftover is expected.

I tried to play with `mallopt(M_MMAP_THRESHOLD)` with no result.

What else can be done in order to find the leak?

UPDATE:

i add here steps that i tried and a way that worked - maybe it can be useful to someone.

the functions themselves are tested with sanitizers in unit tests.
valgrind crashes the app before the main training loop starts. So this direction was a dead end.

i wanted to collect memory stats from `glibc`. unfortunately `mallinfo` is useless, `mallinfo2` is not available on ubuntu20 and `malloc_info` prints too much. so i tried to use `jemalloc` and its function `malloc_stats_print` for stats.

the stats looked ok. but app behavior changed - virtual memory still grew (up to 75GB) but the resident memory stayed stable (~20GB) and the app worked with no memory issues.

then i tried to run my app without `jemalloc` but with a periodic call of `malloc_trim(0)` and it behaved the same way as `jemalloc` (virtual memory grew but resident memory stayed stable).

conclusion: sometimes `malloc_trim` can fix an issue that looks like a leak.

[a good article about it](https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2021/taming-memory-fragmentation-in-venice-with-jemalloc)

Comment: I don't think there's proof of a memory leak here.  Freeing memory does not guarantee that your OS will stop reserving that memory for your process.

Comment: @DrewDormann i know but VM constantly grows and malloc-allocated memory does not

Comment: Turn on address sanitizer and run the sucker through valgrind. See what they think.

Comment: [Force memory release to the OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32683699/force-memory-release-to-the-os)

Comment: At this point, you haven't demonstrated a problem. What does `-fsanitize=address` or `valgrind` say?

Comment: You should try https://github.com/vmware/chap

Comment: If you do try chap, perhaps look at the output of the following chap commands first: "summarize writable", "count used", "count free", "count leaked"

Comment: updated the question with a possible fix